# $().html() is appending instead of overwriting

Tags: jquery, html

in my project : hoasted at :http://dochyper.unitec.ac.nz/iwd19s1/1525/sethil01iwd/hidden/project2/index.html

download project files: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1N6ZMCECEZlWQIE9EB51B0Uaw-EZcu4l1/view?usp=sharing

I am trying to remove all the dynamically created html elements on button click using the following function:

```
function showBookTicketsScreen(){
    $("#roomLayout").empty();
}
```

how ever it is not removing the html inside the #roomLayout div.

the result i want is  https://i.stack.imgur.com/lNM09.png

[image]

but on going back and pressing the submit button again 
the result is that .html() is appending new elements into #roomLayout
like here:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/mEISs.png

[image]

Comment: `$("#roomLayout").html('');`

Comment: @zer00ne is that working for you ? i just tried it but it didnt work

Comment: `$("#roomLayout").empty();` also works in console -- both divs are removed.

Comment: you probably have a different issue rather than the .html alone.

Comment: Files have been removed as it can not be shared with other students at my college

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I read your source code. **parseXML** function appends parsed data on every function call. You should initialize **html** variable inside **parseXML** function as below.

**script.js**

```
var xmlHTTPobject= new XMLHttpRequest();
var html=""; // <= The variable won't be cleared at every function call.
function parseXML(filePath){
    var html=""; // <= Initialize inside the function.
    xmlHTTPobject.open("GET",filePath,false);
    xmlHTTPobject.send();
    var xmlRespsonse = xmlHTTPobject.responseXML;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just manually empty the HTML content:

```js
function showBookTicketsScreen() {
  $("#roomLayout").html("");
}

function more() {
  $("#roomLayout").append("Text<br>");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<button onclick="showBookTicketsScreen()">Empty</button>
<button onclick="more()">More text</button>
<p id="roomLayout"></p>
```

Comment: hi I tried doing that but it seems to not work in my setup, is it working for you ?-Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#append').click(function() {
  $('#roomLayout').append('More stuff<br/>');
});

$('#clear').click(function() {
  $('#roomLayout').html('');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="append">Append</button>
<button id="clear">Clear</button>

<div id="roomLayout">Some stuff<br/></div>
```